# PHP DOM Document not parsing / retrieving HTML

Tags: php, html, parsing, dom, request

I wrote the following:

```
<?php 
$str = 'http://stackoverflow.com';
$DOM = new DOMDocument;
$DOM->loadHTML($str);

//get all H1
$items = $DOM->getElementsByTagName('h1');

//display all H1 text
for ($i = 0; $i < $items->length; $i++)
{
    echo $items->item($i)->nodeValue . "<br/>";
}
?>
```

And just wanted to simply retrieve all the H1 elements of stackoverflow, but can't get it working. Whenever I try filling in the variable $str manually (for example: `<h1>hello</h1><div><h1>hello2</h1></div>`) it is working. But whenever I try to parse content from another webpage it is not doing anything at all...

Help would be appericiated!

Comment: @splash58 Content is being retrieved, thank you so much! :) On the side, how am I possible to retrieve the whole HTML code? instead of just only the nodeValue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$str = 'http://stackoverflow.com';
$DOM = new DOMDocument;
$DOM->loadHTMLFile($str);   // get html

echo $DOM->saveHTML();  echo html
$DOM->saveHTMLFile(FILE_NAME); save html to file
```

Comment: And what if I want to echo out a specific element? Would this be the way on how to use it? echo $DOM->getElementsByTagName('h1')->saveHTML();

Comment: `$nodes=$DOM->getElementsByTagName('h1'); foreach($nodes as $node)  $DOM->saveHTML($node);`

Comment: Thank you so much for your time, I may am annoying, after asking this. But could you may add another explanation of your code & update the answer so I (and everybody else) can understand what we're dealing with? Thanks!

Comment: You are welcome! Ok, i will update my answer in some minutes